# How can I get the income details from the below xml for each employer tag?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xpath, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I've been trying to parse an XML file(I've pasted the minimal reproducible code below) and get the values of Year and income fields for all the income tags for every employer code. Please see the following output so that you can understand me better

What I'm trying to get:

```
{"1234": [["2006", "12085"], ["2005","23071"], ["2004","21364"]],
"5678" : [["2015", "12345"],["2014", "13071"]]}
```

I've been trying and meddling with the file in so many ways using elementtree and/or beautifulsoup to finally print only this:

What I actually got:

```
[["2006", "12085"], ["2005","23071"], ["2004",["2015", "12345"],["2014", "13071"]]
```

I'm unable to group them based on their employer code.

PS: I'm a newbie to posting questions at Stackoverflow. I hope I meet all the community guidelines.
This is XML that is eating my brain:

```
<DETAILS>
    <RESPONSE>
        <EMPLOYER>
            <EMPLOYERCODE>1234</EMPLOYERCODE>
            <NAME1>ABC Service Corporation</NAME1>
        </EMPLOYER>
        <INCOME>
            <YEAR>2006</YEAR>
            <TOTAL>12085</TOTAL>
        </INCOME>
        <INCOME>
            <YEAR>2005</YEAR>
            <TOTAL>23071</TOTAL>
        </INCOME>
        <INCOME>
            <YEAR>2004</YEAR>
            <TOTAL>21364</TOTAL>
        </INCOME>
        <ID>18700763721</ID>
    </RESPONSE>
    <RESPONSE>
        <EMPLOYER>
            <EMPLOYERCODE>5678</EMPLOYERCODE>
            <NAME1>DEF Service Corporation</NAME1>
        </EMPLOYER>
        <INCOME>
            <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
            <TOTAL>12345</TOTAL>
        </INCOME>
        <INCOME>
            <YEAR>2014</YEAR>
            <TOTAL>13071.73</TOTAL>
        </INCOME>
        <ID>18700763721</ID>
    </RESPONSE>
</DETAILS>
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the responses first, because they contain both employer code and the income statements. Then it's just connecting employers to their incomes.

```py
xml = '''
<DETAILS>
    <RESPONSE>
        <EMPLOYER>
            <EMPLOYERCODE>1234</EMPLOYERCODE>
            <NAME1>ABC Service Corporation</NAME1>
        </EMPLOYER>
        <INCOME>
            <YEAR>2006</YEAR>
            <TOTAL>12085</TOTAL>
        </INCOME>
        ...
    </RESPONSE>
    <RESPONSE>
        ...
    </RESPONSE>
</DETAILS>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'html.parser')
employers = {}
for res in soup.select('response'):
    emp_code = res.select_one('employercode').text
    incomes = []
    for income in res.select('income'):
        year = income.select_one('year').text
        total = income.select_one('total').text
        incomes.append([year, total])
    employers[emp_code] = incomes

print(employers)
```

output:

```
{'1234': [['2006', '12085'], ['2005', '23071'], ['2004', '21364']], '5678': [['2015', '12345'], ['2014', '13071.73']]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I exactly wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the elementtree version of this problem

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('_filename_.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
dic ={}
for child in root:
    for schild in child:
        if schild.tag=='EMPLOYER':
            emp=schild[0].text
            dic[emp]=[]
        if schild.tag=='INCOME':
            arr=[]
            arr.append(schild[0].text)
            arr.append(schild[1].text)
            if emp not in dic:
                dic[emp]=arr
            else:
                dic[emp].append(arr)
print(dic)
```

output:

```
{'1234': [['2006', '12085'], ['2005', '23071'], ['2004', '21364']], '5678': [['2015', '12345'], ['2014', '13071.73']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize dict comprehension and BeautifulSoup'get_text()`method and then split`` data. This results in very short code:

```
data = '''<DETAILS>
... your data ...
</DETAILS>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
data = {response.select_one('employercode').text: [i.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|') for i in response.select('income')] for response in soup.select('response')}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
{'1234': [['2006', '12085'], ['2005', '23071'], ['2004', '21364']],
 '5678': [['2015', '12345'], ['2014', '13071.73']]}
```